# In C#, how to iterate through collections more efficient and remove code duplication?

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
public Data GetData(DataSettings settings)
{
    return GetData(x => settings.RepositoryIds.Contains(x.Key));
}

private Data GetData(Func<KeyValuePair<Guid, IRepository>, bool> predicate = null)
{
    var item = new Data();
    if (predicate != null)
    {
            item.ACollection.AddRange(_provider.AllElements
                .Where(predicate)
                .Where(x => x.Value is IA)
                .Select(pair => MakeAItem(pair.Value)));

            item.BCollection.AddRange(_provider.AllElements
                .Where(predicate)
                .Where(x => x.Value is IB)
                .Select(pair => MakeBItem(pair.Value)));
    }
    else
    {
        item.ACollection.AddRange(_provider.AllElements.Values.Select(MakeAItem));
    }
    return item;
}
```

I have a collection that contains all elements `AllElements`. But I iterate through this collection three times. How can I do this more faster?

And maybe I can get rid of last `else` ?

Update

This will be more efficient or not?

```
  var first = _provider.AllElements.Where(predicate).Where(x => x.Value is IA).ToList();
  var second = _provider.AllElements.Where(predicate).Except(ACollection);

  item.ACollection.AddRange(first.Select(pair => MakeAItem(pair.Value)));
  item.BCollection.AddRange(second.Select(pair => MakeBItem(pair.Value)));
```

Comment: In else block did you mean `item.ACollection.AddRange` instead of `item.A.AddRange`? Also, don't you want to consider BCollection in else case? Edit: Also why there is no `.Where(x => x.Value is IA)` condition in else block?

Comment: Yes, thanks. No, I don't

Comment: Maybe you can receive better answers if you provide a https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Is `AllElements` a dictionary?  If so, it would be faster to iterate the values in `settings.RepositoryIds` and look for a corresponding value in `AllElements`.

Comment: @juharr Yes, its a dictionary

Comment: Do you ***actually know*** that you have a **performance issue**?

Comment: You should run timing tests to see which is faster, but I doubt your alternative would perform better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to have a way to iterate the keys you want to look up instead.  Your current algorithm is iterating over all the key value pairs in `AllElements` and for each one it's doing a `Contains` on the `settings.RepositoryIds` which is a linear search.  So the complexity is O(mn) where m is the number of repository ids and n is the number of items in the dictionary.  That's worse than the fact that you're running it twice.  Instead if you iterate the ids and look them up in the dictionary the complexity will be O(m) because a dictionary lookup runs in constant time.

```
public Data GetData(DataSettings settings)
{
    return GetData(settings.RepositoryIds);
}

private Data GetData(IEnumerable<Guid> keys)
{
    var item = new Data();

    foreach(var key in keys)
    {
        IRepository value = null;
        if(_provider.AllElements.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            if(value is IA)
                data.ACollection.Add(MakeAItem(value));
            if(value is IB)
                data.BCollection.Add(MakeBItem(value));
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what to do if `keys` is empty collection(null)?

Comment: @Anatoly Well the code here duplicates what will have in your original code if the collection is empty.  It creates a `Data` object and doesn't add anything to the `ACollection` and `BCollection` collections.  If you want to do something else then just check if the collection is empty with `Any`.  Additionally you can check if the collection is `null` as well, but your current code would have a run-time exception if `settings.RepositoryIds` is `null` as would the code above..

Answer (score 1):

A simple refactor:

```
public Data GetData(DataSettings settings)
{
    return GetData(x => settings.RepositoryIds.Contains(x.Key));
}

private Data GetData(Func<KeyValuePair<Guid, IRepository>, bool> predicate = null)
{
    var item = new Data();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<Guid, IRepository> kvp in _provider.AllElements) 
    {
        if (predicate != null)
        {
            if (predicate(kvp)) 
            {
                IA aValue = kvp.Value as IA;
                if (aValue != null) 
                {
                    item.ACollection.Add(MakeAItem(aValue)); // uses: AItem MakeAItem(IA a);
                }

                IB bValue = kvp.Value as IB;
                if (bValue != null) 
                {
                    item.BCollection.Add(MakeBItem(bValue));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            item.ACollection.Add(MakeAItem(kvp.Value)); // uses: AItem MakeAItem(IRepository repo);
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a **foreach** loop in this case will be more efficient. instead of the .Where methods you will be using a if/else statement. this prevents the multiple iterations of the .Where extension method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a foreach to iterate only once through the items from _provider.AllElements:

```
private Data GetData(Func<KeyValuePair<Guid, IRepository>, bool> predicate = null)
{
    var item = new Data();
    if (predicate != null)
    {
        foreach (var element in _provider.AllElements.Where(predicate))
        {
            if (element.Value is IA)
                item.ACollection.Add(MakeAItem(x.Value));
            else if (element.Value is IB)
                item.BCollection.Add(MAkeBItem(x.Value));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        item.ACollection.AddRange(_provider.AllElements.Values.Select(MakeAItem));
    }
    return item;
}
```